# How to assign integer values to object data type values in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-object

Let's say we have data frame as below:

### **Name       Sex**

John   -    Male

Melissa -   Female

**Data type**:

Name -> object

Sex -> object

What would be the best way to assign integer values 1 and 2 to Male and Female values respectively in Sex column.

Note : I am using python 3.6.

Comment: create a Person class with name and sex attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign integer values to object data type values.

```
>>> name = ['John','Melissa']
>>> sex = ['Male', 'Female']
>>> name_sex = []
>>> for i in sex:
...     if i == 'Male':
...             name_sex.append(1)
...     else:
...             name_sex.append(2)
...
>>> print(name_sex)
[1, 2]
```

Combining name and sex

```
>>> name_sex1 = []
>>> list1 = list(map(str, name_sex))
>>> list1
>>> for i, j in zip(name, list1):
...     a1 = ' '.join([i, j])
...     name_sex1.append(a1)
...
>>> for i in name_sex1:
...     print(i)
...
John 1
Melissa 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear.
You may use something like
data['Sex'] = data['Sex'].map({'Male': 0, 'Female': 1})

If you are doing this for Machine Learning Problem, you may have to change the data type to categorical for better learning rather than string or integer.

Comment: Yes, I am working on a machine learning problem. I will try to change the data type to categorical. Thanks for your reply!